# Flask project, setup Price field

Tags: html, flask-wtforms

I have problem with setup price field.
I wanna make field only with numbers, but i can write in him symbols like "dsajdaslkdja".
My code

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, IntegerField, validators, RegularExpression
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    price = IntegerField('Price', [validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=10000)] )
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

my form

```
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.price.label(class="form-number-label") }}
        {% if form.price.errors %} 
            {{ form.price(class="form-number form-number-lg is-invalid") }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.price.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.price(class="form-number form-control-lg") }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import NumberInput

price = IntegerField('Price',[validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=10000)], widget=NumberInput())
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27108616)

Comment: then im using it i get error ```SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument```

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot